# TFS 2010 Multiple condition for a work item field in TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I am using TFS 2010.
My requirement is to set allowed values for a field based on two conditions.

I have tried using nested WHEN, but i got error and i found in the forums that it is not possible.

How can I achieve this?

1. Field ‘Step’ value of “Code Review” and the field ‘Test Group’ value was “UAT only”, then the selection in the field ‘Step’ drop down would be “Code Review”, “Unit Test”, or “UAT”
2. Field ‘Step’ value of “Requirement”, then have the selections in the drop down box “Requirement”, or “Design”

**For Example**

```
<FieldDefinition name="Assigned To" >
   <WHEN field="System.AreaId" value="9">
     <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true" filteritems="excludegroups">
       <LISTITEM value="1" />
     </ALLOWEDVALUES>
   </WHEN>
   <WHEN field="System.StateId" value="103">
     <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true" filteritems="excludegroups">
       <LISTITEM value="2" />
     </ALLOWEDVALUES>
   </WHEN>
 </FieldDefinition>
```

In the above XML, System will check OR condition either Area ID = 9 or StateID = 103. But my requirement is to check AND condition, if both the condition satisifies, then i have to set few allowedvalues.

Answer (score 0):

The way I typically handle this is just to combine the 2 fields into one, and give all possible combinations as allowed values.

So for example you might have a drop-down with the following choices:

```
UAT Only - Code Review 
UAT Only - Unit Test 
UAT Only - UAT 
Requirement - Requirement
Requirement - Design
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply dylan. But any other way to have two conditions for a field ? . The solution that you gave cant be implemented in my case.